# magento2 custom module installation from git using composer

Tags: magento2, module, installation, composer, git

how to install my custom module on another magento2 project from git using composer

I tried with composer `config ->this` works fine.

when I run composer require its shows an error

```
[RuntimeException]                                                           
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror
```

anybody, please explain to me to install a custom module by this method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the ordering of repositories - we're using satis to as a private package server. For some reason, satis says that the dev-master branch is available, but wouldn't correctly provide it (it works for tags, though).

By changing the file so that the git repo is listed ahead of satis, it works:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.amh.net.au:amh-framework/amh-test.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://svn.amh.net.au:8002"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "amh-framework/amh-test": "dev-master"
    }
}
```